# How to get array data when have conditions in php

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist

I have temp.txt file that contains

```
-------------------|
-------------------V
2016/11/2 23:49:34,1,2,3,5 <---Array 0
2016/11/2 23:49:35,2,2,3,9 <---Array 1
2016/11/2 23:49:36,0,2,3,5 <---Array 2
2016/11/2 23:49:37,0,5,3,5 <---Array 3
2016/11/2 23:49:38,0,2,3,5 <---Array 4
2016/11/2 23:49:39,1,2,3,5 <---Array 5
2016/11/2 23:49:40,2,2,3,5 <---Array 6
2016/11/2 23:49:41,3,2,3,5 <---Array 7
2016/11/2 23:49:42,4,2,3,5 <---Array 8
2016/11/2 23:49:43,5,2,7,5 <---Array 9
2016/11/2 23:49:44,0,2,3,5 <---Array 10
2016/11/2 23:49:45,0,2,3,5 <---Array 11
2016/11/2 23:49:46,0,3,5,7 <---Array 12
```

I want to add last array by split 0,0 in row[1]
so the answer is:

```
Array1 row[1]+array9 [1] = 7
```

how in order to make the process if have many rows of data.

```
<?php
$file    = file_get_contents('temp.txt');
$rows    = explode("\n", $file);
foreach($rows as $row)
{
    //get row data
    $row_data = explode(',', $row);
    $data  = $row_data[1];
    echo $data;
    echo '<br />';
}
?>
```

Actually the data in temp.txt is random, and so many line data. if the last digits before 0 is not in line 1 and 9 but the data in line 35, line56, and line100. I can not decide the line manually when getting the random data. What should i do to get the data is automatically?

My goal to get the sum of the data based on random data before 0.

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: Have you tried something? Did you mean like this http://phpio.net/s/11i2 ?

Comment: As already mentioned, your question is not clear. Can you provide a simple example of what you try to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand it...
You want the two values surrounded with stars?

```
-------------------|
-------------------V
2016/11/2 23:49:34,1,2,3,5 <---Array 0
2016/11/2 23:49:35,**2**,2,3,9 <---Array 1
2016/11/2 23:49:36,0,2,3,5 <---Array 2
2016/11/2 23:49:37,0,5,3,5 <---Array 3
2016/11/2 23:49:38,0,2,3,5 <---Array 4
2016/11/2 23:49:39,1,2,3,5 <---Array 5
2016/11/2 23:49:40,2,2,3,5 <---Array 6
2016/11/2 23:49:41,3,2,3,5 <---Array 7
2016/11/2 23:49:42,4,2,3,5 <---Array 8
2016/11/2 23:49:43,**5**,2,7,5 <---Array 9
2016/11/2 23:49:44,0,2,3,5 <---Array 10
2016/11/2 23:49:45,0,2,3,5 <---Array 11
2016/11/2 23:49:46,0,3,5,7 <---Array 12
```

I think the following code will do what you want.

```
$textdata = "2016/11/2 23:49:34,1,2,3,5 <---Array 0
2016/11/2 23:49:35,2,2,3,9 <---Array 1
2016/11/2 23:49:36,0,2,3,5 <---Array 2
2016/11/2 23:49:37,0,5,3,5 <---Array 3
2016/11/2 23:49:38,0,2,3,5 <---Array 4
2016/11/2 23:49:39,1,2,3,5 <---Array 5
2016/11/2 23:49:40,2,2,3,5 <---Array 6
2016/11/2 23:49:41,3,2,3,5 <---Array 7
2016/11/2 23:49:42,4,2,3,5 <---Array 8
2016/11/2 23:49:43,5,2,7,5 <---Array 9
2016/11/2 23:49:44,0,2,3,5 <---Array 10
2016/11/2 23:49:45,0,2,3,5 <---Array 11
2016/11/2 23:49:46,0,3,5,7 <---Array 12";

preg_match_all("/\:\d{2},(\d)/", $textdata, $arr);

$sum = $arr[1][1]+ $arr[1][9];
echo $sum; // 7
```

The preg_match_all will look for strings that are semicolon two numbers a comma and a single digit number.
All the single digit numbers are then stored in the output array `$arr[1]`

https://3v4l.org/mnnin

UPDATE:

```
$file = "2016/11/2 23:49:34,1,2,3,5 <---Array 0
2016/11/2 23:49:35,2,2,3,9 <---Array 1
2016/11/2 23:49:36,0,2,3,5 <---Array 2
2016/11/2 23:49:37,0,5,3,5 <---Array 3
2016/11/2 23:49:38,0,2,3,5 <---Array 4
2016/11/2 23:49:39,1,2,3,5 <---Array 5
2016/11/2 23:49:40,2,2,3,5 <---Array 6
2016/11/2 23:49:41,3,2,3,5 <---Array 7
2016/11/2 23:49:42,4,2,3,5 <---Array 8
2016/11/2 23:49:43,5,2,7,5 <---Array 9
2016/11/2 23:49:44,0,2,3,5 <---Array 10
2016/11/2 23:49:45,0,2,3,5 <---Array 11
2016/11/2 23:49:46,0,3,5,7 <---Array 12";

// $file    = file_get_contents('temp.txt');
$rows    = explode("\n", $file);
$i = 0;
$sum = 0;

foreach($rows as $row)
{
    //get row data
    $row_data = explode(',', $row);
    $data  = $row_data[1];
    if($i == 1|| $i == 9){
        $sum = $sum + $data;
    }
    //echo $data;
    //echo '<br />';
    $i++;
}

echo $sum;
```

https://3v4l.org/fY6Ke

Update AGAIN!

```
$file = "2016/11/2 23:49:34,1,2,3,5 <---Array 0
2016/11/2 23:49:35,2,2,3,9 <---Array 1
2016/11/2 23:49:36,0,2,3,5 <---Array 2
2016/11/2 23:49:37,0,5,3,5 <---Array 3
2016/11/2 23:49:38,0,2,3,5 <---Array 4
2016/11/2 23:49:39,1,2,3,5 <---Array 5
2016/11/2 23:49:40,2,2,3,5 <---Array 6
2016/11/2 23:49:41,3,2,3,5 <---Array 7
2016/11/2 23:49:42,4,2,3,5 <---Array 8
2016/11/2 23:49:43,5,2,7,5 <---Array 9
2016/11/2 23:49:44,0,2,3,5 <---Array 10
2016/11/2 23:49:45,0,2,3,5 <---Array 11
2016/11/2 23:49:46,0,3,5,7 <---Array 12";

// $file    = file_get_contents('temp.txt');
$rows    = explode("\n", $file);
$i = 0;
$sum = 0;
foreach($rows as $row)
{
    //get row data
    $row_data = explode(',', $row);
    $data  = $row_data[1];
    if($data == 0){
        $sum = $sum + $PrevRow;
    }
    $PrevRow = $data;
    $i++;
}

echo $sum;
```

https://3v4l.org/2ngJ2

Comment: @PratamaDArief that is something you should have told us earlier.... Updated my answer

Comment: how to determine
$sum = $arr[1][?]+ $arr[1][?];
using a loop

Comment: This line: `if($i == 1|| $i == 9){` if you want to add say line 5 with 6: `if($i == 5|| $i == 6){`

Comment: What if the last digit before 0 is not in line 1 and 9. Data in temp.txt is random, and so many line data. if the last digits before 0 are 3,6,10, i can't decide the line  manually when getting the random data. What should i donto get the data automatically?

Comment: So is that what you are looking for? You should edit your question and tell us EXACTLY ALL what you need and how to calculate it.

Comment: It work!! thanks for understand my question...
actually i'm beginner in php program...

Thanks

Comment: @PratamaDArief :-) Then you should accept my answer.